# Code used to parse input throws InputMismatchException

Tags: java, io

```
while(inputbook.hasNext()){
    id = inputbook.nextInt();
    name = inputbook.next();
    year = inputbook.nextInt();
    price = inputbook.nextDouble();
    Book b = new Book(id,name,year,price);
    hmbook.put(id,b);
    Book b2 = hmbook.get(id);
    System.out.println(b2);

    getCb3();
    cb3.addItem(name);
}
```

And this is the text file:

```
100 JAVA 2007 100.0
200 C++ 2005 65.9
300 Introduction 2008 120.0
```

But I'm getting an `InputMismatch` exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at FirstFrame.loadFiles(FirstFrame.java:143)
    at FirstFrame.<init>(FirstFrame.java:712)
    at FirstFrame$7.run(FirstFrame.java:699)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is the exception. Why does it happen?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing more about the context. Have you set the delimiter to anything other than whitespace? Do you read anything from the scanner in your getCb3 method?

Comment: Change your code to

`while(inputbook.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(inputbook.next());
}`

to verify that you're actually reading what you think you're reading.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that your locale expects doubles to use commas as decimal separator. You could try

```
Scanner inputbook = new Scanner(new File("book.txt"));
inputbook.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

and see if that changes anything. I'd also add

```
while(inputbook.hasNext()){
    id = inputbook.nextInt();
    System.out.println("id=" + id);
    name = inputbook.next();
    System.out.println("name=" + name);
    year = inputbook.nextInt();
    System.out.println("year=" + year);
    price = inputbook.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("price=" + price);
```

That way you'll know what the last successfully read variable was, and it will be easier to determine what went wrong.

Comment: +1 The problem is definitely on the decimal separator based on the current locale.